# Quarterly report in Gnucash?

Tags: gnucash

Gnucash has this handy Account Summary report, which summarizes all incomes and expenses in every currency in the current fiscal year.

I'd like to see a similar report for a custom date range (say, April 1 - June 30) but I can't find anything like this in the options. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: This is more a question about software support than about actual finance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Account Summary report, which summarizes all incomes and expenses in every currency **in the current fiscal year.**

This is wrong. Account Summary is formally known as "Trial Balance". It is a snapshot of all accounts on a given date. This means that this report shows all income and expenses since you opened the books, or the last time you closed the books. This could be more than 1 year, or even 10 years of expense.

Basic Financial Statement includes at least two things: Balance Sheet and Income Statement. For GNUCash they can be found under [Reports -> Assets & Liabilities -> Balance Sheet] and [Reports -> Income & Expense -> Income Statement].

Balance Sheet is a snapshot of Assets and Liabilities on a single day. Whereas an Income Statement represents Income and Expense in a period.

This means asking "What is the Balance Sheet from April 1 - June 30" does not make any sense. You may only ask "What is the Balance Sheet on June 30".

As for Income Statement from April 1 - June 30, after going into [Reports -> Income & Expense -> Income Statement], you may use [Options -> General -> Start Date/End Date].

There is no reason to use "Account Summary". The last important Financial Statement is "Cash Flow".

For more information read [this](http://valueinvestingbasics.com/stock-vs-flow-concepts-in-accounting/).